# How to save draft of form by erasing any fields that fail validation in MVC4

Tags: forms, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

We need users to be able to save a draft of their form in MVC4.
We already implemented a "Save Draft" button which disables the 
client side validation entirely and submits the form.

Now on the server side the plan is to ignore any form fields which 
have validation errors.  For example, if a zip code field has "abc"
then we'll ignore that field and save the rest.  If any field are 
required but not provided those will also be ignored.

We're trying to figure out an elegant way to do this in MVC4 via
IModelBinder.

```
public class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var result = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        if (!controllerContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach( var state in controllerContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState)
            {
                if( state.Value.Errors.Count > 0) {
                    var fieldName = state.Key;
                    // Clear original data field that has the error.
                }
            }
            // Now redo the binding without the fields that presented a problem.
            result = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

So the problem above is how to clear the specific field data so that it can re-run
the data binding and generate the model without the fields that cause validation errors?

Comment: @Inanikian I tried this.  state.Value = string.Empty;  It says Value cannot be assigned to. Tried state.Value.Value same problem. And state.Value.Value.RawValue  same problem and state.Value.Value.AttemptedValue same problem

Comment: @Inanikian those all say that set is unaccessible.  I just found this.   modelState.SetModelValue(state.Key, "");  But it needs ValueProviderResult insteat of "".  How to provide an empty ValueProviderResult?

Comment: I think you can make then a research on `ValueProviderResult`

Comment: @Inanikian This compiles so testing it now:  modelState.SetModelValue(state.Key, new ValueProviderResult("","",null));

Comment: ValueProviderResult(
 Object rawValue,
 string attemptedValue,
 CultureInfo culture
)

Comment: @Inanikian  that's not working. Even after calling the SetModelValue...it still constructs the model with the invalid data.

Comment: tell me invalid data are there an error? Because if this line :` if( state.Value.Errors.Count >0)` is false you will have your invalid data. I think you must perfom another condition.